# Algorithms to store and send data

Tags: encryption

I would like to **store** data, and **send** it by mail. What is the best way to encrypt it, and being able to decrypt it? My guess would be RSA, but is there a better way?

(Considering that the other person knows the algorithm and has the key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, RSA is asymmetric; you use it when you are worried that an eavesdropper might learn the key when you exchange it with the other person.

Since you are in the lucky position of having already exchanged the key, you can use a symmetric algorithm. I like AES-128 myself.

Comment: You still need a secure way to exchange RSA public keys. The difference is if the secure channel only needs to offer authenticity or also confidentiality.

Comment: Just my standard addon when dealing with AES: Never use the ECB mode